# How can I seamlessly join 2 sides of my model?

Tags: mesh

I only created half a model then used mirror modifier to make it symmetrical. Now I want to change only one side of the mesh. I tried duplicating but my model is large and would take ages to merge all the vertices to make it a proper model. Any good way to do this?

Comment: Can't you simply apply the modifier? You'll then be able to modify each side independently.

Comment: No. Moving vertices on one side still moves the opposite on the mirrored side.

Comment: It certainly shouldn't do that if the modifier has definitely been applied! Can you upload it so that someone can have a look to see what's going on. - https://pasteall.org/blend/

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, apply your Mirror modifier using this menu or pressing <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> while hovering the modifier:

[image: apply modifier]

Then, in edit mode, make sure you have neither of these symmetry options enabled:

[image: mesh symmetry]